# how to map json data in dropdown list (Functional component)?

Tags: reactjs, mapping, dropdown, react-functional-component

```
export default function FirstStep() {
  const [ageGroup, setAgeGroup] = useState('');

  function getAgeGroup(){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:1190/v1/ageGroup`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }

<Form.Label className="Form-Label">Age</Form.Label>
                  <Dropdown>
                    <Dropdown.Toggle className="Field-Color" style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                      Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

                    <Dropdown.Menu style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                      <Dropdown.Item  >Action</Dropdown.Item>
                      <Dropdown.Item >Another action</Dropdown.Item>
                      <Dropdown.Item >Something else</Dropdown.Item>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                  </Dropdown>
}

my JSON 
[{"id":"1","ageGroup":"6 to 16 years","categories":[{"categoryName":"DANCE","description":"blah blah","imageURL":"imgUrl","styles":["JAZZ","CONTEMPORARY"]}]},
```

{"id":"2","ageGroup":"18 and above","categories":[{"categoryName":"DANCE","description":"blah blah","imageURL":"imgUrl","styles":["HIP HIP","ZUMBA"]}]}]

```
//Mapping is not my strongest front, please let me know how the age group can be mapped into the dropdown.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need is to set the ageGroups when you fetch it and loop over it

```js
   function getAgeGroup(){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:1190/v1/ageGroup`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setAgeGroup(res.data)
      })
  }



         <Dropdown.Menu style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                          {ageGroup?.map((value,indx)=>{
                           return (
                             <Dropdown.Item key={indx}>{value.ageGroup}</Dropdown.Item>
                           )})
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                      </Dropdown>
```

Comment: It's throwing errors. closed the expression firstly, then got ageGroup.map is not a function

Comment: Oh, you initialized the state with an empty string however it should be an empty array like this   const [ageGroup, setAgeGroup] = useState([]);